# Isolating global changes between modules in node.js

Tags: node.js, global-variables

It seems like if I modify, say, Object.prototype, that seems to be visible across all modules. It would be very nice if these global changes could be isolated so that a module is protected from being affected by modules is *doesn't* require.

Is this in any way possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Object.prototype` is an object, and there's only one of it, so modifying it in one place affects all references to that object (just like any object). This is generally considered a benefit since it makes modules like [colors](https://github.com/marak/colors.js/) possible. It shouldn't be necessary *protect* modules from changes made to global prototypes, since those changes should only be extensions. If your, or someone else's, modules are modifying built-in methods/properties, then that's probably bad practice in the first place.

Although you didn't give an example, I would think you probably want to either create local functions (not attached to the prototype), or look into using [inheritance](http://nodejs.org/api/util.html#util_util_inherits_constructor_superconstructor) to solve your concerns with specific objects.

Comment: Yeah I suppose what you're saying makes sense. However, with this scheme, there is always the possibility that two extensions collide - ie create the same name on an individual object.

Comment: You're absolutely right. If you're really worried about it, you might take a lesson from how C libraries handle this (typically with library-specific prefixes/suffixes). In practice, I've never seen it happen in node. Modules simply don't edit global object prototypes very often.